# gradient of gradient is it Hessian?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Say, I have a function $f(\vec{x}) = \cfrac{1}{2}\vec{x}^{T}Q\vec{x} - \vec{b}^T\vec{x}$, where $Q$ is Symmetric Positive Definite $\in R^{nxn}$.

I want to find $\nabla f(\vec{x} - \nabla f(\vec{x}))$.

So, am I solving this correctly like the following?
I know that,
\begin{equation}\nabla f(\vec{x}) = Q\vec{x}-\vec{b}\end{equation} 
So,
\begin{equation}\nabla f(\vec{x} - \nabla f(\vec{x})) = \end{equation}
\begin{equation}= (Q(\vec{x} - \nabla f(\vec{x})) - \vec{b})\nabla(\vec{x} - \nabla f(\vec{x})) = \end{equation}
\begin{equation}= (Q(\vec{x} - \nabla f(\vec{x})) - \vec{b})(\nabla\vec{x} - \nabla \nabla f(\vec{x})) = \end{equation}
\begin{equation}= (Q(\vec{x} - \nabla f(\vec{x})) - \vec{b})(\vec{1} - \nabla^2 f(\vec{x})) = \end{equation}

So, can I say that $\nabla \vec{x} = \vec{1}\quad \text{and} \quad\nabla \nabla f(\vec{x}) = \nabla^2 f(\vec{x})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct until partial difference of $f(\mathbf{x})$. Next, the vector $\mathbf{x} - \nabla f(\mathbf{x})$ is replaced  for $\mathbf{y}$. Therefore,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}
&=\mathbf{x}-\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) \\
&=\mathbf{x}-(Q\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}) \\
&=(E-Q)\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}
\end{align}
$$

Then, $E$ is an identical matrix. So, the calculation $\nabla f(\mathbf{x}-\nabla f(\mathbf{x}))$ can be described as follows.

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla f(\mathbf{x}-\nabla f(\mathbf{x}))
=& \nabla f(\mathbf{y}) \\
=& Q\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{b} \\
=& Q\{(E-Q)\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}\}-\mathbf{b} \\
=& Q(E-Q)\mathbf{x}-(E-Q)\mathbf{b}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can we write $Q(E−Q)\mathbf{x}−(E−Q)\mathbf{b} = (Q-I)(E-Q)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b})$ or somehow simplify?

Comment: No, If the equation is $(E-Q)Q\mathbf{x}-(E-Q)\mathbf{b}$, it can be solve into factors as $(E-Q)(Q\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b})$. But, these are matrices so that it cannot be interchange.